# Pseudo-element formatting not working

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

I have this CSS:

```
sqrt::before {
  border: none;
  content: "√";
}
sqrt {
  content: attr(expr);
  border-top: 1px solid black;
}
```

The `::before` pseudo-element has a border.

I intentionally specified `border: none;` to avoid this.

Comment: and the sqrt has a border ... show us the html anddwhat do you expect, etc etc

Comment: what is **sqrt** and what is the question?

Comment: @TemaniAfif: Just wrap some text in a sqrt tag.

Comment: @manishkumar: 1. It's a shorthand for "square root".

Answer (score 0):

There is no border on the `::before`. The issue is that your `::before`-element is inside the `sqrt`-element.

Try this code:

```
sqrt::before {
  border: none;
  content: "√";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
}
sqrt {
  content: attr(expr);
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  margin-left:2px;
}
```

It positions the `::before` absolute to the `sqrt`-element, and moves the `sqrt`-element away from the `::before`, therefore creating the desired effect.

[Working JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/09c0q8tn/1/)